# Number of conditions hit in a Regex containing multiple rules separated by OR condition

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a Regex with OR conditions in it. I want to find the number of conditions satisfied out of all the conditions that are present in the Regex separated by an '|'.

Example : `(.*Begin.*)|(.*Middle.*)|(.*End.*)`

I also have a string like : `"Hello this is Begin.Hello this is Middle."`

Now if you see 2 of the 3 or conditions in the Regex would hit in this rule.
I want to find the number of conditions hit.

I do not want to split the Regex based on '`|`' and then apply each one individually.I want to run the entire Regex at once.

The order of the submatches is not always Begin-->Middle-->End in the string that we are searching. It's a completely random string where we apply the Regex which contains conditions combined into one Regex. I want to know as to how many of those conditions in the Regex got hit.

Comment: Split it into 3 regex (manually, not using `Split` method), and check them separately.

Comment: @nhahtdh...I do not want to spilt the Regex into three and introduce a loop to check each of them....Thats the whole point in merging the conditions so as to avoid looping the rules

Comment: @Mohnish This isn't something that standard regular expression engines support. Feel free to implement your own, but that's a bit broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Mohnish, can you please provide a solved example ?

Comment: Just what is the problem with running three separate regex?

Comment: @Rawling - Technically, it is possible to do with .NET regexes via zero-width assertions, but I will be the first to admit that it gets unwieldy quickly.

Answer (score 2):

In short, this isn't possible using standard alternation. Once text has been matched, it can't be matched again. Also, once the expression is satisfied, it will not continue searching. If Regexes attempted to match every possible permutation, they would be extremely ineffecient and no one would use them.

While your question isn't addressed explicitly in the documentation, that I can find, it is covered under the topic of backtracking. See MSDN's [Backtracking with Optional Quantifiers or Alternation Constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx#backtracking_with_optional_quantifiers_or_alternation_constructs).

Essentially, your alternation list (`.|.|.`) creates an opportunity for backtracking. If the first alternate doesn't match, then the second will be attempted. This backtracking does not occur, however, unless the first alternate fails, and once a match is made all other alternates are ignored.

If you want to match multiple expressions, you could use lookaheads like so:

```
string l_pattern = @"(?i)" + /*make the regex case-insensitive*/
                   @"(?=(?<Cond1>.*?Begin)+)?" +
                   @"(?=(?<Cond2>.*?Middle)+)?" +
                   @"(?=(?<Cond3>.*?End)+)?";

string l_input = "Oops - I put the middle first!" + 
                 "Hello this is Begin.This is another begin.";

var l_match = Regex.Match( l_input, l_pattern );

Console.WriteLine( "Cond1 matched {0} times.",
                   l_match.Groups["Cond1"].Captures.Count );
Console.WriteLine( "Cond2 matched {0} times.",
                   l_match.Groups["Cond2"].Captures.Count );
Console.WriteLine( "Cond3 matched {0} times.",
                   l_match.Groups["Cond3"].Captures.Count );

Console.ReadKey( true );
```

This will output:

> Cond1 matches 2 times.
>   Cond2 matches 1 times.
>   Cond3 matches 0 times.

Lookaheads do not capture any text, so they function kind of like a mini-regex within the regex. Essentially, this expression is no different from just running all three expressions separately. (Take care to note that each lookahead is optional, otherwise the entire expression would fail if any one of the lookaheads failed.)

Also note that when using lookaheads as I have shown, the order doesn't matter.

For more on lookaheds, see MSDN's [Zero-width positive lookahead assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion). The topic is a little too big to address fully on an SO answer.

I can't say I'd recommend this approach over all others - it can be difficult to maintain if you are not familiar with regexes and it's not necessarily the most effecient pattern, but it fits your stated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("Begin|Middle|End");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
numberOfMatches = allMatchResults.Count
```

Comment: The question is to find the number of conditions that hit, not the number of matches.

Comment: @nhahtdh: You are right (if at least one of the alternatives could match more than once).

Comment: @TimPietzcker One more doubt that I have is that...won't these conditions in the Regex work in a short circuit way....as in if the first condition is satisfied in the target string,it wont check the remaining conditions at all....so how would we identify if the target string also satisfies the second condition and so on.....am I right ???

Comment: @Mohnish: No, the `.Matches()` methods finds all non-overlapping matches, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex fragments match mutually exclusive set of languages (or a weaker but harder to verify condition is that they match non-overlapping substrings in the input string), then you can find all matches  and count the number of capturing groups that constitute a match in the string.

If the regex fragments match overlapping substrings, then the simplest way is to try to match each of the regex fragments against the string and count.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
(.*Begin|Middle|End.*)
```

and find the number of matches returned by the RegEx engine.

Something like this would help you:

```
MatchCollection mcoll = Regex.Matches("sample string to match","(.*Begin|Middle|End.*)")
int count = mcoll.Count
```

Also, if you wish to do a case-insensitive match prefix this pattern with `(?i)` so the pattern will look like:

```
(?i)(.*Begin|Middle|End.*)
```

Hope it helps!